# Utilizar type/interface com v-model em Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Sou novo no TS e estou com problema no uso em Vue3.
Tenho um formulário responsável por visualização/edição/adição de uma ocorrência. Logo, preciso que uma ou mais interface/type supra as minhas necessidades quanto ao Vue, quando o formulário estiver em um dos três estados: populado, parcialmente populado ou vazio.

Ex:

```
interface pessoa {
 nome: string
 endereco: {
  rua:string
  cidade:string
 }
}

interface parcialPessoa extends Partial<Pessoa>{}
```

Na maioria dos casos o Partial atende tornando tudo opcional. Porem, ao bindar com v-model uma propriedade do objeto interno **endereço** ocorre o erro, pois o próprio endereço é opcional, então pode ser que ele não exista.

```
<template>
 <!-- aqui gera erro, pois endereco pode ser undefined -->
 <input v-model="viewData.endereco.rua" 
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const viewData: ParcialPessoa = reactive({ });
</script>
```

Já implementei algoritmos recursivos para cada chave da interface a fim de substituir o Partial, ajudou, mas não resolveu este problema. Gostaria de saber se existte uma solução inteligente sem eu precisar duplicar todas as interfaces a fim de adequar para isso, no caso, modificar a interface original a fim de criar uma nova e então utiliza-la.